# Using VB to Create Outlook 2013 HTML Message

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to make Outlook 2013 create a new HTML message using my HTML file. The code below creates a new email message, but it does not include my HTML file. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
Public Function CreateHTMLMsg(fileHTML As String) _
  As Outlook.mailItem
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FileExists(fileHTML) Then
        Set objOL = Application
        Set objMsg = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileHTML, _
                                        ForReading)
        objMsg.HTMLBody = objStream.ReadAll
    End If
    Set CreateHTMLMsg = objMsg
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Function

Sub sdnewsletter()
    Set objMsg = CreateHTMLMsg("C:\Users\...\index2-inline.html")
    objMsg.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to read HTML into a variable and look at it in the debugger to make sure you read the right data?

Comment: The error was the use of On Error Resume Next. The editor could not tell you the error message and in turn you could not tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Scripting reference in Visual Basic Tools>References. Then this works, but Outlook will still strip media queries and change CSS (e.g., EMs to PXs).